# kgefec: fatal error 0 kgepop: no error frame to pop to for error 21503 on tomcat startup

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, caching

I am using tomcat 6 and Java 1.5. In our application we have 2 scenario
1) Disable cache memory and use DB for data
2) Enable cache memory option and load DB data in in-memory cache

when I am using 1st option my tomcat is starting up withing minute and application is working fine. 
To use second option i need to increase my heap memory. I am following below steps to increase my jvm heap size:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/setting-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap-eclipse/

I set -Xms512m and -Xms1024m as heap size. My application was working fine with these settings previously.

But surprisingly from yesterday I am getting below error while tomcat startup when i am using cache enable option:

> kgefec: fatal error 0
>
> kgepop: no error frame to pop to for error 21503

If I used 1st option i.e. cache disable I am not getting any error.

The Data in DB remain same its not increased. I tried following options but did not get any success:
1) uninstall JAVA and re-install
2) downloaded another tomcat and configured that

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was using oci url to get DBconnection now i changed it to thin. After that it started working.